# boost::trim in lambda causes compiler crash

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

I am having a problem with lambda expression causing compiler to crash (VC10).

It only seems to crash when I use boost::trim on a string. Is there any logical explanation to why this happens and any way to fix that behaviour ? Or will I have to do trimming manually inside the lambda ?

This is sample code that causes the crash:

```
CreateBtn.MouseUpEvent += ([this](const input::MouseEventArgs& args)
{
    Res.BlendBaseName = BlendTb.GetText(); 
    //boost::trim(Res.BlendBaseName); this line causes compiler internal error
});
```

MouseUpEvent is object of my class that just wrapps vector of std::functions if this is helpful in any way.

Calling other functions from within the body of lambda works, but boost::trim fails. It seems to me as a compiler bug. Any ideas?

Edit: This is the message in Output Window:

```
1>d:\development\lame\lame_framework_test\editormode.h(243): fatal error C1001: An internal error has occurred in the compiler.
1>  (compiler file 'msc1.cpp', line 1420)
```

Comment: Show the internal compiler error

Comment: I have edited the post, but the message itself is not really descriptive.

Comment: Submit a bug report to MS and ask them for a better compiler?

Comment: There's only one possible explanation to any compiler crash or other internal error: *there's a bug in the compiler, and you have hit it*. There's no sense in being gentle and saying "I *suspect* a compiler bug" or "there *seems to be* a compiler bug". There **is** a bug and you have a proof in your hands.

Comment: In any case it's not a good idea to mix up boost and C++/cli code. STL has special Microsoft specific realization for using with C++/cli.

Comment: @Forgottn, It is not C++/cli. It is native C++. Anyway I replaced boost::trim with own implementation and it works.

Comment: I have the same problem. :) So it is not that you just have corrupted install. :)